# inquality question

Tags: inequality

I was just asked the following question(not on this website but by a friend):

---

> $A = 2015x^2 + 2015y^2 + 6z^2$
>
> $ B = 2(2012xy + 3yz + 3zx)$
>
> Which is correct?
>
> - A > B
> - B > A
> - A = B
> - Relationship cannot be determined

---

I don't understand how you can compare the two unless it was in reference to something measurable like perimeter, area or volume.  So should the answer be relationship cannot be determined?

Comment: I can't see how you could conclude any of the relationships with the given information, so I would say you're right

Comment: Before you can write any of those, you need to tell us what **definition** of "<" you are using here.  There is no standard order on polynomials of several variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** : Method 2

The following expression is positive (sum of squares)

$$\frac{4027}{2}(x-y)^2+\frac{3}{2}(x+y-2z)^2$$

You can expand it and find it is equal to

$$\frac{4027}{2}(x^2+y^2) - 4027xy + \frac{3}{2}(x^2+y^2)+6z^2-6zx-6zy+3xy$$

$$ \frac{4030}{2}(x^2+y^2)-4024xy+6z^2-6zx-6zy$$

This is exactly equal to $A-B$. Hence $A\geq B$

**Method 1:**

Matrix of quadratic form $A-B$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2015 & -2012 & -3 \\ -2012 & 2015 & -3 \\ -3 & -3 & 6\end{pmatrix}$$

It has eigenvalues $0$, $9$ and $4027$, that is to say positive. Hence $A>B$ (well actually $A\geq B$ because of $0$ eigenvalue) (matrix are symmetric)

Note 1 : writing $A>B$ makes perfect sense if $A$ and $B$ are real polynomials and if the inequality holds for all $x,y,z$. If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric matrixes, $A>B$ means $A-B$ is positive matrix.

Note 2 : if you are not familiar with quadratic forms, you can always write some equation such that $a x^2 + b y^2 + 2 c x y$ using expression $(x \quad y) \begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ c & b\end{pmatrix} (x\quad y)^T$ (same for 3 dimensions with 3x3 matrix). The polynomial is positive if the matrix in the middle is positive. Being positive for a symmetric matrix means all its eigenvalues are positive.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably your friend wants you to show that $A\ge B$ for *all* real values $x,y,z$.  (Note, however, that "$A\ge B$" is not one of the options, just "$A\gt B$."  Also, your friend neglected to mention the "for all" business.) The inequality $A\ge B$ can be demonstrated by noting that

$$\begin{align}
0&\le2012(x-y)^2+3(y-z)^2+3(z-x)^2\\
&=2012(x^2-2xy+y^2)+3(y^2-2yz+z^2)+3(z^2-2zx+x^2)\\
&=(2015x^2+2015y^2+6z^2)-2(2012xy+3yz+3zx)\\
&=A-B
\end{align}$$